# EF Context missing a collection

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to generate an entity from my SQL database using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model using the [ADO.NET DbContext Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/32c4660d-7e66-4c3a-b516-584f4f72b838). When I generate my edmx from the database I can see it in the model. I right click on my tt file (which is in a separate project) and run the custom tool. The entity appears. It's called CustomerContact. However, my dbcontext does not have a CustomerContacts collection. What is going on here?

Comment: Does the tool support your version of Entity framework? I have used PowerTools https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d for Code Second in EF6 with no big problem. The tool you mentioned supports EF5.

Comment: Not sure where to look for this. I'm looking at Manage Nuget packages and I see I'm using EF 6.1.3 in my EDMX project and EF 6.1.3 in my tt project, but when I look in the projects' references they both say 6.0.0.0. Will this cause a problem?

Comment: I guess it may because this tool you have used is rather old and the latest support is for EF 5 on their webpage.

Comment: OK I may not be using this version of the context generator. How do I find out which version it is?

Comment: I suppose you have installed it from here? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/32c4660d-7e66-4c3a-b516-584f4f72b838

Comment: I can't remember. Where is it in the solution explorer?

Comment: It is not in the Solution Explorer, it is a VS project type, as you wrote `ADO.NET Entity Data Model using the ADO.NET DbContext Generator`, ... Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791170/purpose-of-ef-6-x-dbcontext-generator

Comment: Great thanks for your help. I can figure it out now

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was the different versions of Entity Framework. I updated both projects to the latest version of EF and it works now